# Microsoft Team Foundation Server Express 2012 - How to clean up in tbl_TestResult (old test results)

Tags: tfs

I have installed a Microsoft Team Foundation Server Express 2012.

The table tbl_TestResult is using up 7000 MB of my Database space.

I tried to find information on how to clean up this Table but found no way to do so.

When I want to check in new files into TFS I get the Error TF30042: The database is full...

Over the Visul Studio I deleted all visible Tests but still the size of tbl_TestResult just decreased very little.

Can anyone explain to me how I can cleanup all test results in a proper way?

Answer (score 2):

I am using the TFS client API to delete old test runs. Here's some sample code:

```cs
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfs2012:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/"));

TestManagementService testManagementService = tpc.GetService<TestManagementService>();

ITestManagementTeamProject teamProject = testManagementService.GetTeamProject("MyProject");

int totalRuns = teamProject.TestRuns.Count("SELECT * FROM TestRun");

// Limit by date, so the query doesn't take too long.
string query = "SELECT * FROM TestRun WHERE CreationDate < '2013/07/01'";
int numTotalToDelete = teamProject.TestRuns.Count(query);

if (numTotalToDelete == 0) { return; }

// Only delete 500 at a time, to give SQL Server time to breathe (don't ask).
var runsToDelete = teamProject.TestRuns.Query(query, false)
                              .Take(500);
teamProject.TestRuns.Delete(runsToDelete);
```

Query syntax comes from here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/duat_le/archive/2010/02/25/wiql-for-test.aspx

Comment: This worked great, thanks! Take into account that it takes a while for TFS to actually catch up with your command and delete the rows from the database.

Comment: Couple things incase anyone hits issues/questions on this: 1) The classes above can easily be accessed by the Nuget packages Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client and Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient (I added both but you may only need one or the other). 2) Our Url did not end in 'DefaultCollection', by looking at our url for accessing tfs normally I figured out what ours was.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue for our on prem TFS. This is how we did it for TFS 2015 up to TFS 2017.

1. Install [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power) to get access to Test Attachment Cleaner(TAC), **tcmpt.exe**.
2. It installs to `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools`
3. Sample settings for TAC is located in the installation folder, at `<INSTALL_DIR>\TestAttachmentCleaner_samples_settingsfile`
4. Create your own settings file, for example, `all-100mb.xml` file:

```xml
<DeletionCriteria>
<TestRun>
    <Created Before="2016-01-01" />
</TestRun>
<Attachment>
    <Extensions>
    <Include value="wmv" />
    <Include value="xesc" />
    <Include value="trmx" />
    </Extensions>
    <!-- size in MB -->
    <SizeInMB GreaterThan="100" />
</Attachment>
<LinkedBugs>
    <Exclude state="Active" />
</LinkedBugs>
</DeletionCriteria>
```

5. The above config file removes test attachments of inactive test runs which are larger than 100MB with extensions: wmv, xesc, trmx.
6. Perform a test attempt to find out the outcome with this command: `tcmpt.exe AttachmentCleanup /settingsfile:"all-100mb.xml" /mode:preview /collection:"https://tfs.contoso.com/DefaultCollection" /teamproject:"TeamProjectName" /outputfile:all-100mb.log"`
7. This produces a very detailed log file that includes key information you needed, like:

   `------------ Summary ------------
   Number of attachments affected: 339
   Total size of attachments: 39646,7 MB
   Elapsed time was 247,94 seconds`
8. When you are satisfied with the result, do this:

   - Turn off transaction logs for your TFS database, if you use MSSQL server.
   - If you don't, you may grow your transaction logs faster than you can remove the test attachments.
9. Run `tcmpt.exe` command above without the `/mode:preview` parameter to delete test attachments.
10. When done, run these 2 stored procedures from the TFS database:

    `EXEC dbo.prc_DeleteUnusedContent 1
    EXEC dbo.prc_DeleteUnusedFiles 1, 0, 1000`

    - The stored procedures removes emptied rows from the database.
    - If the stored procedures last less than 1 second each, wait some time and re-run them again.
11. Then you can choose to shrink your database.

Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

if you delete unwanted builds then you will be presented with the option to delete test results associated with the build when you delete it.
[image: TFS Build Delete options]

You may find that the test attachments are consuming a lot of space as well, you can use the test attachment cleaner provided with TFS power tools to remove these.

TFPT can be found [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I deleted all Builds previously via UI. But still the table lost just slightly size. The TFPT Attachment Cleaner unfortunately just cleans Attachments (as the name suggests) but not the TestResult Table.

Comment: how long after did the file size remain the same, some data is not 'cleared' until the TFSJobAgent kicks in and does a housekeeping exercise. you could always use the tfsbuild destroy command to permanently delete the build rather than just a logical delete that the delete function provides